# Jquery regex validate customer address

Tags: jquery

I wrote below code to validate custom address but could not make it work

I want to allow all alphabets , number , blank space , and symbol like : **-_.,/** only below my code does not works please help me to fix it.

```
$('.allowall').keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_/ ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Rahul Patel's answer is correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following regex will allow alphabets , number , blank space and symbols(-_,.) in the address.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-._ ]*$
```

Please check this link http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95879

```js
$('.allowall').keypress(function(e) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-._ ]*$");
  var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="allowall"/>
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but perhaps you could make a test snippet?

Comment: @JosephCallaars thanks for your suggestion. The snippet has been included.